# Alternatives to scipy.optimize Newton-CG for minimization if I have the Hessian?

Tags: python, scipy, gradient-descent, minimization

I've got a complicated, nonlinear problem to minimize, but I have analytic expressions for the Jacobian and Hessian. I'm currently using `scipy.optimize.minimize` with the Newton-CG method and am looking to test some alternative methods. Can anyone recommend packages that have other python minimization routines that use pre-computed Hessians and not numerical approximations?

Comment: In my experience, if you have the 1st and 2nd derivatives, the trust region method works quite well. I once tried the [`trust-ncg` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-trustncg.html#optimize-minimize-trustncg) on a 30-something-dimensional problem with satisfactory results. Method based on [trust regions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_region) tend to converge more nicely than plain conjugate gradient.

Comment: You might also want to check out `trlib` ([repo](https://github.com/felixlen/trlib), [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.04718)) that has a Python binding. It's also included as a method for `scipy.optimize.minimize` since version 1.0.0.

Comment: Yeah I tried many of those `trust-*` algorithms in `scipy` and they perform much more poorly than `Newton-CG`.

Comment: AstroBen, @Cong Ma, would either of you know of test cases for trustregion or Newton-CG, say on gist.github ?
Or info on how noisy your gradients are,
or the spectra of some H s along the path ?
(For any two methods A and B, sometimes A will be better, sometimes B.
To understand a bit *why* we need test cases.)
Thanks